# printing specific lines from files in C

Tags: c, windows, file

So, I'm writing a small utility to help me read some files more efficiently, so the program opens a file then prints everything from line 12 till the end. I'm using Windows. So far this is my code:

```
FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    char chr;
    long long ln = 1;
    if (file) {
        while ((chr = fgetc(file)) != -1) {
            if (chr == '\n') ln += 1;
            if (ln >= 12)
                printf("%c", chr);
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
```

But every time I run the program it gives me something like this:

```
X:\example>readln document.txt

line 12
line 13
line 14
...
```

As you can see for some reason it always has this empty line at the beginning for no reason. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Move `if (chr == '\n') ln += 1;` to after `if (ln >= 12) printf("%c", chr);`

Comment: Why are you reading one character at a time, instead of reading the entire line?

Comment: What @KenWhite said plus why use `printf()` to output just a single character? Use `putchar()`!

Comment: Also, this will fail on some OSs, and will incorrectly stop after encountering an 0xFF character on others, because `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bugs:

First, `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, because it needs to return every possible character value as well as the extra value EOF. This value is often -1, but since you are chopping the return value into a `char`, the program will also stop when it encounters the character 0xFF (which it will probably never do with a text file, so this bug is well-hidden).

Secondly, you're incrementing the line number when seeing a `'\n'`, then printing a character at a time. When the 12th line is reached, that will print the `'\n'` at the end of the 11th line. Move the increment down a line after the print.